# Crohn's disease and sauna

Tags: autoimmune-disease

If you have Inflammatory bowel disease (IBD) (for example Crohn's or Ulcerative Colitis) is sauna good for you or bad?

And how often you can go to sauna? Every day?

I think it can be good because or relaxation, but maybe bad because of extreme heat.

I found this [discussion](http://www.crohnsforum.com/showthread.php?t=37664), but it's not clear.

Comment: Why do you think it might be good? Why do you think it might be bad? If you read something on the topic and have a link to share it would help a lot :-)